# How to scan for SUID files in root using Java and access its properties?

Tags: java, linux, security, unix, setuid

I'm a newbie to UNIX systems.
I'm being tasked with finding a SUID file in the root directory and access its file properties to get some things done.

Is there anyway I can write a Java based application to search for files with Sticky bit and access their properties (file permissions/creation date etc.)?

** I have been asked not to use 'find' commands in UNIX for this purpose.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From `Interface PosixFileAttributeView` documentation:

> The permissions attribute is a set of access permissions. This file
>   attribute view provides access to the nine permission defined by the
>   PosixFilePermission class. These nine permission bits determine the
>   read, write, and execute access for the file owner, group, and others
>   (others meaning identities other than the owner and members of the
>   group). Some operating systems and file systems may provide additional
>   permission bits but access to these other bits is not defined by this
>   class in this release.

Means that you can't actually access these bits (setuid and setgid) in Java. Remember that Java is OS agnostic, and such permissions are POSIX specific.

Comment: Is it possible to do in Python?

Comment: This is another question. Open a new one, please. But, search if it doesn't exists already...